Why does fgets() require a maximum size of user input? Is it because it does not have the "restrict to first space" property of scanf()?
This is fgets()'s official prototype:
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream);

Why specify the size (n) ? Is it to prevent buffer overflow of some sort? Or is it just a design flaw?
I would think that it's caused by gets() tendency to cause buffer overflow and segfault your program, but that's only my guess.
In any case, this may be related to the fact that fgets() is a file function, but I would also have no idea.
This is in the context of a recent video on buffer overflow, and in a security context, is this a risk? Is the size a limitation, and in this context, prone to segfaulting?

fgets has a size to prevent buffer overflow. It's absolutely not a "design flaw". When you call fgets you tell the size of the provided buffer and fgets makes sure not to write more data to the buffer than the size. So assuming you call the function correct, there won't be any buffer overflow. That's why fgets is much better than gets. And better than scanf where many programmers forget to specify a size limit. In (at least) 9 out of 10 cases fgets is the best way to read input.

Design flaw?!! Nah, man, this is the opposite of a flaw. scanf() is flawed in all kinds of horrid ways. fgets() is well-designed.

@Dúthomhas — fgets() is reasonably well designed.  It would be better designed if it returned the number of characters it placed in the buffer (either 0 or EOF could indicate EOF).  If the input contains null bytes, you can't tell how many characters were read.

@JonathanLeffler Very true.

In its defence, fgets() works fine on text files and text files do not contain null bytes.  However, it would still be better if it reported the number of bytes read.

As previously written the "size" parameter is to prevent buffer overflow. It's needed as a separate parameter because the called function (here fgets) has no way to know the size of the buffer from the pointer. That's how C is designed. When you pass a pointer or an array to a function, the function can't know the actual size of the "pointed to buffer". So to prevent overflow, the size must be passed as a separate parameter.

You have seen a video on buffer overflow, especially in the context of security. Please elaborate how in that context you see a possible design flaw in the required size parameter. Those two things seem so much in conflict that I wonder what your question is about. To stress the point, please understand that I read your question as "I know about the buffer overflow problem and its security implications. Why is there a size parameter for fgets()?"

@JonathanLeffler s in fgets stands for "string". C string can't contain null bytes.

@JonathanLeffler "text files do not contain null bytes." --> When a text file is encoded using UTF16 (not so rare) or UTF32 (rare), there are often many null characters.  Of course fgets() is not the function to read that type of text file, yet error handling of using the wrong input function is additionally complicated since fgets() and reading null characters has the extra problem you pointed out.

@dimich If I had to name ten people on the planet who knew everything there was to know about C... Jonathan Leffler would be in that list.


Why does fgets() require a maximum size of user input?

To limit the amount of data that is saved - preventing buffer overflow cases.


Why specify the size?

To prevent fgets() from saving too many characters.
It also stops reading characters.
fgets() could have read excess characters in a line and not save them, yet the design is to read up to size - 1 characters and save them and then append a null character.  If the buffer fills without a '\n', the rest of the line remains to be read.

Is it to prevent buffer overflow of some sort?

Yes, this prevents a buffer overflow.  It also stops the reading of characters from the file.

Or is it just a design flaw?

It is by design as a limiting alternate to code like gets() (no longer parts of the C library) and scanf("%s", ... which remains risky.
Other (and later) functions that specify the buffer size are of type size_t.  fgets() with its int size is a minor design flaw.

and in a security context, is this a risk?

Passing in a limiting size reduces risk.

Is the size a limitation, and in this context, prone to segfaulting?

The size reduces segment faults.

Reading a line in C is only partially handled by fgets().
Issues remain (some are pedantic):

How to detect and handle when not all the line was read?

Quieting  unsigned_to_signed warnings that come up when a size_t variable is passed as the size.

Detecting the number of characters read when fgets() unusually reads a null character as strlen(), to find the number read, will stop on the read null character and not the appended one.

Many applications do not want to save the '\n'.  So when the destination is size n, code needs additional helper code to read and save up to n-1 characters and then lop off the possible '\n or maybe still read if the buffer was full.

There are 4 reasons why fgets() stops reading: '\n' read, full buffer, end-of-file detected, rare input stream error occurs.  Additional code must be careful to discriminate.

A size of 0 or negative is a pathological problem.


C deserves a better readline function.

Thank you! This is absolutely amazing and answered my question completely!

From cppreference.com C documentation:

fgets
Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and stores them in the character array pointed to by str
...
count     -   maximum number of characters to write (typically the length of str)

(emphasis is mine)
count is the size parameter named n in your question.
According to the Linux manual page, fgets should read at most n - 1 (i.e. count - 1) bytes:

The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array
pointed to by s until n-1 bytes are read, or ...

So the bottom line:
fgets reads at most n - 1 characters and writes them to str. Since it adds a zero ('\0') termination, it will write at most n bytes.
But anyway - basically, the answer is yes; it is for preventing a buffer overflow when filling str (assuming you pass the proper size of str).
It is definitely not a design flaw.

Kind of funny that the documentation says: "typically the length of str". It's wrong in at least two ways.

Concerning the count. Maybe in means, eg 10 chars which is 0-9 which is 10-1. But, then you need to factor for terminating null.

IMO a better description: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html
